# Find Text and Copy the line to a file

Tags: ruby

Say i have a text file like this :

```
SELL USDCAD 0.99257 0.99653 0.39 -150.1 -8.57% -580.99 1 week ago  Copy 
SELL USDCAD 0.98986 0.99653 0.26 -177.2 -6.75% -457.25 1 week ago  Copy 
SELL USDCAD 0.98711 0.99653 0.17 -204.7 -5.10% -345.37 1 week ago  Copy 
BUY USDCAD 0.98613 0.98715 0.17 8.4 0.21% 14.47 1 week ago  Copy
```

And i am looking for line/lines which has "1 week ago" this string in it. And take it to a variable and write to another text file.

How can i do that?

Comment: Why do this with Ruby? It's a trivial thing to do with `grep` at the command line without writing any code.

Answer (score 2):

is there any reason you have to use ruby for this, when one line from the command line will do the same thing?

```
grep '1 week ago' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
str = <<EOT 
SELL USDCAD 0.99257 0.99653 0.39 -150.1 -8.57% -580.99 1 week ago  Copy 
SELL USDCAD 0.98986 0.99653 0.26 -177.2 -6.75% -457.25 1 week ago  Copy 
SELL USDCAD 0.98711 0.99653 0.17 -204.7 -5.10% -345.37 1 week ago  Copy 
BUY USDCAD 0.98613 0.98715 0.17 8.4 0.21% 14.47 1 week ago  Copy
EOT

content = str.lines.select { |l| l.include? '1 week ago' }.join("\n")
File.open('asdf.txt', 'w') { |file| file.write content }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it from the command-line using:

```
ruby -ne 'print if $_["1 week ago"]' < file_to_read > file_to_write
```